# I have dataFrame as below and want to add remarks based on the column values using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below is my Input

```
id    val  visits  date
111   2        1   20160122
111   2        1   20170122
112   4        2   20160122
112   5        4   20150122
113   6        1   20100120
114   8        2   20150122
114   8        2   20150122
```

Expected Output:

```
id    val  visits  date        remarks
111   2        1   20160122    oldDate
111   2        1   20170122    recentdate
112   4        2   20160122    less
112   5        4   20150122    more
113   6        1   20100120    one
114   8        2   20150122    Ramdom
114   8        2   20150122    Ramdom
```

Remarks should be:
Ramdom for Id has two records with same value & visits & date
One Visit for Id has only one record which contains any no of visits
Less Visit for Id has two records with less visits compared to other
More Visit for Id has more than one record with different value and visits.
recentdate Id has more records with same value & visits and different date with Max date
oldDatedate Id has more records with same value & visits and different date with Min date

code:

```
val grouped = df.groupBy("id").agg(max($"val").as("maxVal"), max($"visits").as("maxVisits"), min($"val").as("minVal"), min($"visits").as("minVisits"), count($"id").as("count"))

val remarks = functions.udf ((value: Int, visits: Int, maxValue: Int, maxVisits: Int, minValue: Int, minVisits: Int, count: Int) =>
   if (count == 1) {
     "One Visit"
   }else if (value == maxValue && value == minValue && visits == maxVisits && visits == minVisits) {
     "Random"
   }else {
     if (visits < maxVisits) {
       "Less Visits"
     }else {
       "More Visits"
     }
   }
 )



df.join(grouped, Seq("id"))
   .withColumn("remarks", remarks($"val", $"visits", $"maxVal", $"maxVisits", $"minVal", $"minVisits", $"count"))
   .drop("maxVal","maxVisits", "minVal", "minVisits", "count")
```

Comment: is that the only input?

Comment: yes that is the input

Comment: What problem are you having? You don't actually say where you ran into an issue.

Answer (score 0):

following code should work for you (but its not efficient as there are many if elses)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def remarkUdf = udf((column: Seq[Row])=>{
  if(column.size == 1) Seq(remarks(column(0).getAs(0), column(0).getAs(1), column(0).getAs(2), "one"))
  else if(column.size == 2) {
    if(column(0) == column(1)) column.map(x => remarks(x.getAs(0), x.getAs(1), x.getAs(2), "Random"))
    else{
      if(column(0).getAs(0) == column(1).getAs(0) && column(0).getAs(1) == column(1).getAs(1)){
        if(column(0).getAs[Int](2) < column(1).getAs[Int](2)) Seq(remarks(column(0).getAs(0), column(0).getAs(1), column(0).getAs(2), "oldDate"), remarks(column(1).getAs(0), column(1).getAs(1), column(1).getAs(2), "recentdate"))
        else Seq(remarks(column(0).getAs(0), column(0).getAs(1), column(0).getAs(2), "recentdate"), remarks(column(1).getAs(0), column(1).getAs(1), column(1).getAs(2), "oldDate"))
      }
      else{
        if(column(0).getAs[Int](0) < column(1).getAs[Int](0) && column(0).getAs[Int](1) < column(1).getAs[Int](1)) {
          Seq(remarks(column(0).getAs(0), column(0).getAs(1), column(0).getAs(2), "less"), remarks(column(1).getAs(0), column(1).getAs(1), column(1).getAs(2), "more"))
        }
        else Seq(remarks(column(0).getAs(0), column(0).getAs(1), column(0).getAs(2), "more"), remarks(column(1).getAs(0), column(1).getAs(1), column(1).getAs(2), "less"))
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    column.map(x => remarks(x.getAs(0), x.getAs(1), x.getAs(2), "not defined"))
  }

})

df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(struct("val", "visits", "date")).as("value"))
  .withColumn("value", explode(remarkUdf(col("value"))))
  .select(col("id"), col("value.*"))
  .show(false)
```

it should give you

```
+---+-----+------+--------+----------+
|id |value|Visits|date    |Remarks   |
+---+-----+------+--------+----------+
|111|2    |1     |20160122|oldDate   |
|111|2    |1     |20170122|recentdate|
|112|4    |2     |20160122|less      |
|112|5    |4     |20150122|more      |
|114|8    |2     |20150122|Random    |
|114|8    |2     |20150122|Random    |
|113|6    |1     |20100120|one       |
+---+-----+------+--------+----------+
```

And you need the following `case class`

```
case class remarks(value: Int, Visits: Int, date: Int, Remarks: String)
```

Comment: @Thanks for the reply, i am facing compile time error at 'def remarkUdf = udf((column: Seq[Row])=>{' the error is  No Typetag available for seq[remarks] and not enough arguments for method udf.

Comment: did you do exactly what I did?

Comment: Yes i did exactly same as you did.

Comment: where did you put the case class

Comment: I kept at the bottom after the method, and i tried in the top of udf method.

Comment: Put it outside the class

Comment: I cant put it outside the class, can't we write the same logic in the code which i have posted in the question. Actually that is working only we have to add one more column Maxdate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168777/discussion-between-ramesh-maharjan-and-chandra).